# How to move code execution to the main qeue

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, nsurlsession, synchronous

I'd like to mention that I've seen a lot of similar questions and tried code from there, but still my code runs asynchronously (I move to another ViewController only after second click on LogIn Button. That's why I would really appreciate you pointing out the problem in my code rather then referencing me to someone's else.

I have a method which sends logIn data to server

```
import UIKit
var IS_LOGGED_IN = Bool()

class LoginDataSender: UIView {
    func sendLogInData() {
        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://somewebsite")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "username=NAME&password=PASS"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data, respoonse, error) in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                do {
                    let myJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                    IS_LOGGED_IN = myJson.valueForKey("status") as! Bool
                    print(IS_LOGGED_IN)

                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            })

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

and I call this method from a ViewController

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    let logInDataSender = LoginDataSender()

    @IBAction func pressLoginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

       logInDataSender.sendLogInData()

        if IS_LOGGED_IN {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("LogInSegue", sender: self)

        } 
}
```

As you see I store result result in a global variable IS_LOGGED_IN and based on that I whether perform segue or not.
For now I just hardcode login/password for testing purposes.

**Where should I place dispatch_async to be able to use IS_LOGGED_IN value when clicking LogIn button for the first time? Thanks a lot!**

Comment: If you've read similar questions then surely you've seen that they all say you need to add a completion handler to your method and perform your segue inside of it.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @dan Yep, thanks to Santosh now I know how to use that.
Sorry, just a few weeks programming for iOS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your global variable, make a practice to use completion handlers. In this your case, you may use like:

```
func sendLogInData(completionhandler: (Bool)->()) {
    //.......
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            do {
                let myJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
                completionhandler(myJson.valueForKey("status") as! Bool)
            } catch {
                completionhandler(false)
                print(error)
            }
        })
    //.....
}
```

And then in your action method of `LoginViewController`:

```
 @IBAction func pressLoginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    logInDataSender.sendLogInData { (loggedIn) in
    if loggedIn == true {
       //Logged In
       performSegueWithIdentifier("LogInSegue", sender: self)
    }else{
       //Not logged in
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Santosh! It works perfect!
I've just added self before performSegueWithIdentifier. High five!

Comment: My reputation is too low, but I've marked your answer. Thanks again!